# *.github.com always be redirected to github.com

Tags: network

When I visited any subsite of `github.com`, for example `help.github.com`, `desktop.github.com`, it was always be redirected to `github.com`. I had tried the follow steps but no luck.

1. clear cache in chrome
2. use another browser (safari)
3. flush dns
4. use `curl help.github.com -v` also got `301 Redirect`

But I can visit *.github.com through my mobile phone from the same Wifi.

What I should do to identify the root cause

---

Update: the output of `curl` command attached below.

```
➜  ~ curl https://help.github.com -v
*   Trying 52.74.223.119...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to help.github.com (52.74.223.119) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Jul  8 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 16 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "help.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: help.github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://github.com/
<
* Connection #0 to host help.github.com left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Can you post the `curl help.github.com -v` output?

Comment: @MartinR updated the question with `curl` output.

Comment: Are you sure that chrome is redirecting to https://github.com.com and not only hiding the "help." in the display?

Comment: @Matteo I'm pretty sure I had redirected to github.com since it's the main page of gihub. Also I saw from Chrome - Dev Tool - Network and `curl` that `help.github.com` returned `301 Moved Permanently` to `github.com`.